# Splunk: Duplicate Fields, different fields - merge

Tags: splunk

I have a number of individual records in Splunk all with a common field of X, which i'm trying to combine.

E.g

```
User-name=JG, srcIP=10.0.0.1
User-name=JG,file=jg.docx
User-name=JG, dstIP=10.1.1.0
User-name=JG,Email=jg@jg.com
User-name=AB, srcIP=10.0.0.2
User-name=AB,file=AB.docx
User-name=AB, dstIP=10.2.2.0
User-name=AB,Email=AB@AB.com
```

I want to do the following search: Group all the records which match by the `User-name` fields, and allow me to manipulate the fields.

E.g

```
USERNAE, srcIP, file, dstIP, Email
JG, 10.0.0.1, jg.docx, 10.1.1.0, jg@jg.com
AB, 10.0.0.2, AB.docx, 10.2.2.0, AB@AB.com
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [stats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.1/SearchReference/Stats) command to do this:

```
your search
| stats latest(srcIP) as srcIP, latest(file) as file, latest(dstIP) as dstIP, latest(email) as email by User-name
```

You can then perform any operations you want to on these fields. The latest function will give you the latest value seen for srcIP/file etc. for that user name.